# PHP FTP Amount Transfered

Tags: php

Is is possible to detect how much data has been transfered using PHP's [FTP module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)?

Pseudo Code

```
... connect to server
ftp_nb_put(file...)
while(true) {
    $data = ftp_nb_continue(file...);
    if ($data === FTP_MOREDATA) {
        continue ... get amount transfered ...
    } else {
        break ... check if finished etc ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know what files you are sending, why not use filesize() to calculate the total amount?

Comment: @John: The OP is trying to find a way to determine how many bytes we sent in each "chunk". Indeed there doesn't appear to be any obvious mechanism to do this in the module's API. It's a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

Strangely (and quite unfortunately), there does *not* appear to be any way to determine how many bytes were uploaded by the previous call to `ftp_nb_continue`, with this PHP extension.

As an aside, you have a few errors:

1. You should check the result of `ftp_nb_put` in the same way that you check for the result of `ftp_nb_continue`, since the transfer begins with the former, not the latter;
2. Your loop stops when `FTP_MOREDATA` is seen, but it should stop only when `FTP_MOREDATA` is *not* seen.

```
... connect to server
$result = ftp_nb_put(file...)
while ($result === FTP_MOREDATA) {
    $result = ftp_nb_continue(file...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I suppose you could get it by reading the filesize via another connection ... though this is unreliable ...

Answer (score 3):

Your probably got an answer by now, but for anyone searching...
This is an ftp upload function with progress callback.
$lcfn = local filename
$rmfn = remote filename

```
function ftp_upload($conn, $lcfn, $rmfn, $progress)
{
    $ret = false;

    $_pc = -1;
    $totalBytes = filesize($lcfn);

    $fp = fopen($lcfn, 'rb');

    $state = @ftp_nb_fput($conn, $rmfn, $fp, FTP_BINARY);

    if($state !== FTP_FAILED){

        while($state === FTP_MOREDATA){

            $doneSofar = ftell($fp);
            $percent = (integer)(($doneSofar / $totalBytes) * 100);

            if($_pc != $percent){
                $progress($percent);
                $_pc = $percent;
            }

            $state = @ftp_nb_continue($conn);
        }

        if($state === FTP_FINISHED){

            if($_pc != 100){
                $progress(100);
            }

            $ret = true;

        }else{
            //error: not finished
        }
    }else{
        //error: failure
    }

    fclose($fp);
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone want to show a the upload progress while doing file transfers, this is a great library [php-ftp-client](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-client) to start :

The code

```
$interval = 1;
$ftp->asyncDownload('illustrations/assets.zip', 'assets.zip', function ($stat) use ($interval) {
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();

    echo sprintf(
        "speed : %s KB/%ss | percentage : %s%% | transferred : %s KB | second now : %s <br>",
        $stat['speed'],
        $interval,
        $stat['percentage'],
        $stat['transferred'],
        $stat['seconds']
    );

    ob_flush();
    flush();
}, true, $interval);
```

Result in the browser :

[image]